# Create a routes to a controller without model with a /id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, routes

I have product with a foreign collection_id key

I want to pass an id to a controller.
To do so i have the following routes for my controller :

```
controller :magasin do

  get "magasin" => "magasin#index"
end
```

The only view in my controller is magasin/index.html.erb

The link to magasin is `link_to collection.nom,  magasin_path(collection)`

This kind of syntax usually works in controllers with models. Here my link is : `http://localhost:3000/magasin.2` instead of `http://localhost:3000/magasin/2`

Later on i will need to call the same view with product_kind_id instead of collection_id and i will add sort by name/price ....

How can i have the ID as a normal argument (`/:id)`instead of a type(`.id`)?

Answer (score 1):

A popular URL schema to follow is [RESTful routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html). Rails has this built-in and will set it up for you if you initialize your resource via `rails generate scaffold Magasin nom:string`.

If you put `resources :magasins` in your routing file, it will route `/magasins` to `MagasinsController#index` and `/magasins/1` to `MagasinsController#show` with `params[:id]` set to `"1"`. It will also set up a few other routes that will be useful in the future but for now will just raise an action not found exception.

You don't want to use the dot as an argument delimiter, since Rails places what comes after the dot in the `request.format` method or just in `params[:format]` (ordinarily accessed through the `respond_to` method that comes with the generated scaffolds). Save that dot for later when you are working on delivering alternative display formats like XML and JSON.

I realize I've said a lot in a small space, so feel free to ask any follow up questions once you've consulted the [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default) on the issue, and I'll be very glad to help!

Comment: My RESTful routes for product are already used for the back-office, now i want to display the products by collection or by type. collection and type also have there default RESTful routes taken by back office.
I want a view (and the links to access it) displaying the products belonging to a collection or a type. I created a controller (generate scaffold controller magasin index) to display that. Whant i need is to do a link passing the parameters so that i can in a display the collection name and the products belonging to this collection.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what your resource association structure is like, but when filtering a list of a resource based on properties of associated resource, your canonical options are to append a query string or to use nested routes. To view all products belonging to collection 1, you'd visit `GET /products?collection_id=1` or `GET /collections/1/product`, putting the handler for `params[:collection_id]` in your `ProductsController#index`.

Comment: how do i create a /products?collection_id=1 link ?

Comment: By Rails default, `GET /products?A=B&C=D` will route to exactly what `GET /products` routes to. What comes after the `?` is something called a query string, which Rails then parses into the `params` object/method as I mentioned above.

Comment: but how do i write the link_to?

Comment: Oh, sorry about that! I misread your question. You can look at the spec for [link_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) to figure that out. What you want is is something like `link_to products_path(:collection_id => 1)`, or, if you have the nested routes set up, you are also free to use `link_to collection_products_path(1)` or `link_to collection_products_path(@collection)` where `@collection` is the instance of something that inherits or implements `ActiveRecord::Base`. There are a half dozen ways to formulate that path. Just pick one.

Comment: Thanks, it works great with :

link_to collection.nom, magasin_path(:collection_id => collection)

Comment: Semantically, `collection` should only even be used to refer to the collection object itself. If you're instead storing the **id** in it, you'd best call that variable `collection_id`.